# Measuring sensor with two PLCs

Tags: plc, automation

Can I measure one sensor with two PLCs? 
I have a PLC that's part of a machine manufacturing stuff.

Another PLC is part of a robotic arm that needs to grab the piece.

It would be intresting to be able to read a number of sensors into both PLCs.

However I end up frying the sensors.

The sensor is a photovoltaic sensor that outputs a simple '1' (24V) or '0' (0V).

Comment: What communication protocol are you using?

Comment: It might be easiest to just have one PLC read the sensor and then send that reading to the other.

Comment: Just a simple sensor connected to the PLC. It only has to give '1' (24V) or '0' (0V) as an output

Comment: @Felthry the problem is that it's very hard to access either PLC's

Comment: Use a relay with 2 contacts, or an opto-coupler? Hard to say without more information. Datasheets for PLC inputs and Sensor, etc.

Comment: I'd think frying sensors is very hard.  You have two easy options, use two sensors or explore how you get the two PLCs to talk to each other.

Comment: I chose not to let the plc's talk to each other cause it costs too much clockspeed.

Comment: You don't have to use a Communication Protocol (High usage) as you say, just wire a digital output from one PLC to an input on the other.

Comment: @Ruben: "*... sensor that outputs a simple '1' (24V) or '0' (0V).*" More likely it is PNP which either pulls high or open-circuits (not the same as 0 V) or is NPN and pulls low or open circuit. Show the schematic circuit for the arrangement that is giving problems including where you have connected the power supplies on both machines. There's a CircuitLab schematic button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: @Transistor Ofcourse you're 100% right. I was looking at the issue from a completely wrong perspective.

Comment: @Ruben: Can you edit your question to clarify or, if you have solved your problem, you can write an answer yourself and accept it to indicate that it's solved.

Answer (score 1):

a voltage signal can be shared between PLCs if they both share the same ground voltage.

that said the sensor needs a 24V supply that supply should be provided in such a way that with one of the PLCs turned off there will be no malfunction. 
this may mean  carefully chosing which PLC is responsible for powering it, or powering it from both using a pair of diodes to prevent back-feeding power.

current signals  (eg 4-20mA loop) cannot be shared as easily.

Comment: Instead of having a PLC provide power to the sensor, you can have a separate field power supply that's independent of either PLC power.`current signals (eg 4-20mA loop) cannot be shared as easily??` I don't know where you got that from. A 4-20mA sensor/transmitter can drive many devices connected in series as long as you don't exceed the rated resistance and you are on a common power source. If on different power sources, you can use signal isolators.

Comment: I was uinder the impression that most PLC  4-20 inputs were gounded one side and a voltage source the other,  but yeah if there are passive inputs they could share it.

Comment: No with 4-20mA, it's a current loop so you don't have grounds at the devices but at the voltage source itself. In most cases, there are no grounds at all.